# Where should be defined an action on entity

Tags: symfony

sorry because my question is dum but I prefer to ask to organize correctly my code.

Actually, in a Controller, I do an action like 'get entity + set activated + persist + send a mail'.

I know this should be placed somewhere else to be usable by others controllers.

I guess that it should be a service, but I got an hesitation, it could be in the model? but given the send mail action, I'm not sure.

I know this is something that may have been discussed in the past, I just couldn't find a clear explanation about that.

There is an official page for business logic on Symfony but not clear about that: http://symfony.com/doc/current/best_practices/business-logic.html

Thank's in advance for your help

Comment: Yeah, you should move that logic from the controller into an Application Services, and model each use case there. About the "send a mail", just dispatch an event. Leave the responsibility of sending the email to the event listener

Answer (score 1):

You should create custom services and add them to the servicecontainer. This link will help you: http://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container.html#creating-configuring-services-in-the-container